# Reading start time in the loop, and if the base time is different from the time set in the loop, assign the result A + time from the base

Tags: c#

How can I create a new loop to check if the time is different from the time set in the loop, and if it is to get the result in the form A: + (datetime)

This is my code in the loop:

```
DateTime von = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["Start_Time"]);
if (von.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(07, 45, 0) && von.TimeOfDay <= new TimeSpan(8, 5, 0))
{
    von = new DateTime(von.Year, von.Month, von.Day, 8, 0, 0);
}
else if (von.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(06, 45, 0) && von.TimeOfDay <= new TimeSpan(7, 5, 0))
{
    von = new DateTime(von.Year, von.Month, von.Day, 7, 0, 0);
}
else if (von.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(12, 15, 0) && von.TimeOfDay <= new TimeSpan(12, 35, 0))
{
    von = new DateTime(von.Year, von.Month, von.Day, 12, 30, 0);
}
else if (von.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(10, 45, 0) && von.TimeOfDay <= new TimeSpan(11, 05, 0))
{
    von = new DateTime(von.Year, von.Month, von.Day, 11, 0, 0);
}
else if (von.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(07, 15, 0) && von.TimeOfDay <= new TimeSpan(07, 35, 0))
{
    von = new DateTime(von.Year, von.Month, von.Day, 07, 30, 0);
}
```

Example Idea:

```
if(von != 8,0,0)
    else if(von != 7,0,0)
    else if (von != 12,30,0)
    else if ( von != 11,00,0)
    else if (von != 07, 30,0)
    else( von = "A" + von)
```

This is my example (it's not true, of course, but I need it) I can not explain it better .. this is my previous loop, von is the time reading from the base and always given him a new time in the loop.

my code

```
private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestControl.Properties.Settings.DB"].ConnectionString))
        {
            boAPI4.Login login = new boAPI4.Login();
            string cS = login.GetConnectionString();
            DataAccess dA = new DataAccess(cS);
            int userID = dA.getLpeID(login.GetBoUserNr());
            PRAESENZZEIT q = new PRAESENZZEIT();

            q.ZPZ_LPE_ID = userID;
            if (db.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                db.Open();
            string query = "SELECT zei.ZPZ_Von, zei.ZPZ_Bis, per.LPE_Nr, zei.ZPZ_LPE_ID, zei.ZPZ_Datum, SUM (zei.ZPZ_Std100) AS ZPZ_Std100" +
                           " FROM DB.dbo.Z_PRAESENZZEIT zei INNER JOIN DB.dbo.A_PERSONAL per ON zei.ZPZ_LPE_ID = per.LPE_ID" +
                            $" WHERE zei.ZPZ_Datum BETWEEN '{dtFromDate.Value}' AND '{dtToDate.Value}' AND zei.ZPZ_LPE_ID='{userID.ToString()}' GROUP BY per.LPE_Nr, zei.ZPZ_LPE_ID, zei.ZPZ_Datum, zei.ZPZ_Von, zei.ZPZ_Bis ORDER BY zei.ZPZ_Datum, per.LPE_Nr;";

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, db))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        var items = new BindingList<PRAESENZZEIT>();
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            PRAESENZZEIT pra = null;


                            DateTime datum = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["ZPZ_Datum"]);


                            DateTime von = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["ZPZ_Von"]);


                            if (von.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(07, 45, 0) && von.TimeOfDay <= new TimeSpan(8, 5, 0))
                            {
                                von = new DateTime(von.Year, von.Month, von.Day, 8, 0, 0);
                            }
                            else if (von.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(06, 45, 0) && von.TimeOfDay <= new TimeSpan(7, 5, 0))
                            {
                                von = new DateTime(von.Year, von.Month, von.Day, 7, 0, 0);
                            }
                            else if (von.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(12, 15, 0) && von.TimeOfDay <= new TimeSpan(12, 35, 0))
                            {
                                von = new DateTime(von.Year, von.Month, von.Day, 12, 30, 0);
                            }
                            else if (von.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(10, 45, 0) && von.TimeOfDay <= new TimeSpan(11, 05, 0))
                            {
                                von = new DateTime(von.Year, von.Month, von.Day, 11, 0, 0);
                            }
                            else if (von.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(07, 15, 0) && von.TimeOfDay <= new TimeSpan(07, 35, 0))
                            {
                                von = new DateTime(von.Year, von.Month, von.Day, 07, 30, 0);
                            }



                            DateTime bis = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["ZPZ_Bis"]);
                            if (bis.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(18, 15, 1) && bis.TimeOfDay <= new TimeSpan(18, 30, 0))
                            {
                                bis = new DateTime(bis.Year, bis.Month, bis.Day, 18, 15, 0);
                            }
                            else if (bis.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(17, 0, 1) && bis.TimeOfDay <= new TimeSpan(17, 15, 0))
                            {
                                bis = new DateTime(bis.Year, bis.Month, bis.Day, 17, 0, 0);
                            }
                            else if (bis.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(19, 30, 1) && bis.TimeOfDay <= new TimeSpan(19, 45, 0))
                            {
                                bis = new DateTime(bis.Year, bis.Month, bis.Day, 19, 30, 0);
                            }
                            else if (bis.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(12, 30, 1) && bis.TimeOfDay <= new TimeSpan(12, 45, 0))
                            {
                                bis = new DateTime(bis.Year, bis.Month, bis.Day, 12, 30, 0);
                            }
                            else if (bis.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(21, 30, 1) && bis.TimeOfDay <= new TimeSpan(21, 45, 0))
                            {
                                bis = new DateTime(bis.Year, bis.Month, bis.Day, 21, 30, 0);
                            }
                            else if (bis.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(14, 30, 1) && bis.TimeOfDay <= new TimeSpan(14, 45, 0))
                            {
                                bis = new DateTime(bis.Year, bis.Month, bis.Day, 14, 30, 0);
                            }
                            else if (bis.TimeOfDay >= new TimeSpan(17, 30, 1) && bis.TimeOfDay <= new TimeSpan(17, 45, 0))
                            {
                                bis = new DateTime(bis.Year, bis.Month, bis.Day, 17, 30, 0);
                            }

                            pra = items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ZPZ_Datum == datum);
                            if (pra != null)
                            {
                                pra.arbeitszeit = pra.arbeitszeit + (bis - von);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                pra = new PRAESENZZEIT();

                                pra.ZPZ_Datum = datum;
                                pra.arbeitszeit = bis - von;

                                items.Add(pra);
                            }
                        }
                        pRAESENZZEITBindingSource.DataSource = items;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your requirement and the code you show I expect this class to achieve what you need. It offers a public static method `GetCorrectedTime` that takes a DateTime and checks its TimeSpan against the list of lower and upper bound timespans (modelled in the same class).

```
public class BetweenTime
{
    // list of lower and upper timespans
    static List<BetweenTime> BetweenTimes = new List<BetweenTime> {
      new BetweenTime("7:45:0", "8:5:0"),
      new BetweenTime("6:45:0", "7:5:0"),
      new BetweenTime("12:15:0", "12:35:0"),
      new BetweenTime("10:45:0", "11:5:0"),
      new BetweenTime("7:15:0", "7:35:0"),
    };

    // get correctedtime if it is found in the list
    public static string GetCorrectedTime(DateTime input)
    {
        var time =  input.TimeOfDay;
        // find the time in the list for lower and upper values
        // and return its corrected time
        var found = from dtm in BetweenTimes
                    where time >= dtm.Lower && time <= dtm.Upper 
                    select dtm.Upper.Add(new TimeSpan(0,-5,0));

        // if we have found at least one
        if (found.Count() != 0) 
        {
           // check we only have one result
           var difftime = found.Single();
           // add the A and correct the time
           return "A" + new DateTime(
               input.Year,
               input.Month,
               input.Day,
               difftime.Hours,
               difftime.Minutes,
               difftime.Seconds); 
        } 
        else 
        {
           // not found so just output what came in.
           return input.ToString();
        }
    }

    // constructors
    private BetweenTime(string lower, string upper)
       :this(TimeSpan.Parse(lower), TimeSpan.Parse(upper))
    {
    }
    private BetweenTime(TimeSpan lower, TimeSpan upper)
    {
       Lower = lower;
       Upper = upper;
    }
    // fields
    TimeSpan Lower;
    TimeSpan Upper;
}
```

I have run this with the following test inputs:

```
var tests = new [] {
  new DateTime(2017,12,22,6,44,59),
  new DateTime(2017,12,22,6,45,0),
  new DateTime(2017,12,22,6,45,1),
  new DateTime(2017,12,22,7,5,0),
  new DateTime(2017,12,22,7,5,1), 
  new DateTime(2017,12,22,12,20,0),
  new DateTime(2017,12,22,12,35,1),
};

foreach(var test in tests)
{
  BetweenTime.GetCorrectedTime(test).Dump(test.ToString());
}
```

Leading to this result:

[image: test result]

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, can I just copy the entire code? insert now all my code from the project so if you can only include your part on my code (rewrite)